# Yocto determine what recipe a file came from

Tags: yocto, bitbake, recipe

I am trying to determine how I can find what recipe a source file from the build/tmp/work directory came from. Basically normally most of the recipes in the source folder are uri. Then get downloaded and installed to various temp folders. I want to create a patch for some of the files, but I can't seem to figure out which files belong to what recipes.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know if there is a way of doing this in your build folder. However, if you have opkg installed on your image, you can try to execute `opkg search /path/to/file` on your board, it will give you the package, and help you find the recipe name.

Comment: I have seen that command.But since I want to make a patch, I am looking at source files which don't end up in the build

Answer (score 3):

Run `oe-pkgdata-util find-path /path/on/target/to/file`. This will give you the package installing the file. From there, run `oe-pkgdata-util lookup-recipe <pkg-name>`, this will give you which recipe is creating the package. That should be enough to find out which recipe you need to modify. You then need to check whether the file you want to modify is part of the recipe (Yocto artifact) or part of the software that the recipe builds. For the former, you can override the file, for the latter, you can create a patch (you can use devtool to help you create the patch).

Comment: hmm when I run that command on a source file I get "ERROR: Unable to find any package producing path". the file is in /home/user/bsp4.9/buildir/tmp/work/...

Comment: What is the path on the target? It is the path you should use, NOT /home/user/bsp...

Comment: what do you mean "target" ?

Comment: Yocto allows you to build images for machines, or "targets". It's basically the device on which whatever you build with Yocto will run. Basically, I'm asking you the path from the root of the rootfs of the image you're building with Yocto.

Comment: I understand what yocto targets are. I am not sure how that is related to my question. the output images are in "~/bsp4.9/buildir/tmp/deploy/images/imx7ulpevk/" The final file that gets built that i deploy is "fsl-image-validation-imx-imx7ulpevk.sdcard.bz2" so the bitbake target is "fsl-image-validation-imx"

Comment: What is the file you want to patch?

Comment: buildir/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.10.0-r0/qemu-2.10.0/roms/u-boot/include/configs/mx7ulp_evk.h

Comment: It's qemu-native, version 2.10.0, it's in the path. If you don't have a qemu-native recipe, you'll have a qemu recipe with `BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"` in it.
You can create patches with `devtool modify qemu-native` and `git commit` followed by `devtool finish` if I'm not mistaken. Otherwise, a manually crafted patch and bbappend will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Each package's work directory is in a location named `tmp/work/arch/pkg/ver`, where `arch` is a machine architecture string, `pkg` is the base name of the package and `ver` is the version of the package.  The contents of that directory will be a function of the recipe's contents, but source files fetched from a Git repository typically get unpacked to a `git` directory in there.

Since you already know which source file you want to patch, then you know what this directory is.

The corresponding recipe will be a file of the form `pkg_ver.bb`.

So if, for instance, you needed to patch something in `tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/gcc/11.2.0-r0/git` (the sources for GCC version 11.2.0-r0 for an ARMv8a-poky-linux architecture), you should search your `sources` directory for a file named `gcc_11.2.0.bb`, or something similar.  A command like `find sources -name 'gcc*.bb' is a good way to look for it.

In my case (a build based on an NXP-provided manifest), the files in question are:

```
$ find sources -name 'gcc*.bb'

sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc_11.2.bb
sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-source_11.2.bb
sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_11.2.bb
sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-crosssdk_11.2.bb
sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross-canadian_11.2.bb
sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-sanitizers_11.2.bb
sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-runtime_11.2.bb
```

The recipe responsible for the `gcc/11.2.0-r0` directory will be `gcc_11.2.bb`.  You can then examine it to learn how it works.

If this is one of your recipes (unlikely, since you were trying to find it), you can modify it to apply your changes.

If it is an upstream recipe (more likely), then you should create a corresponding `.bbappend` file (e.g. `gcc_11.2.bbappend` containing the code to apply your patches.